# Никак не могу понять, как в TD отладить программу, которую я на писал и в целом понять, все ли работает

Tags: ассемблер

В общем для ВУЗа написал программу, которая вычисляет 2x[i] − y[i] + 1 (x и y - массивы) и записывает в z[i]. При запуске программы в MASM все работает без варнингов. Теперь нужно отладить программу в TD, но помимо того, что в целом ничего не ясно, что и где, программа заканчивается непонятными символами в TD и ошибкой. Гляньте пожалуйста код, может что неверно и очень классно было бы, если бы вы помогли с объяснением работы в TD, желательно на примере моей программы.

```
.8086
.model small
.data?
z WORD ?
.data
x WORD 1,2,3,4
y WORD 2,3,4,5
LenArr=($-x)/2
.code
Start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov cx,LenArr
mov bx,0
mov al,2
L1:
    mov ax,x[bx]
    mul ax
    sub ax,y[bx]
    inc ax
    inc bx
    mov z,ax
loop L1
 mov ax,z[0]
 mov ax,z[1]
 mov ax,z[2]
 mov ax,z[3]
mov ah,4Ch
int 21h
end Start
```

Comment: td должен сразу на страрт кидать, если конечно вы правильно exe модуль собрали, и правильно открыли его в td, вид конесчно будет оличаться, но `mov ds,ax` будет на вторй строке.

Comment: Скажите, а код в целом адекватный? Он работает по логике?

Comment: Навскидку тяжело сказать. Начните с hello world, а потом усложняйте. Запустите модуль без td - если адекватно отработал - адекватный. На экран вывода нету, поэтому  только с помощью td можно увить что посчитало.

Comment: Да у меня задание от ВУЗа такое, так что hello world не прокатит

Comment: Начинают с малого, сначала соберите hello world, сделайте отладку программы из 4-7 операндов, а потом переходите к программам посложнее. Так как вы спрашиваете адекватен ли код - а это не извесно - создайте адекватный 100% работающий код, т.е. hello world, а потом когда это получится - будет смысл брать программу сложнее. Я так думаю.

Comment: длина массива не правильная (в два раза больше). Нужно LenArr разделить не на 2, а на 4